# Database content not displaying when paging in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, pagination

I've been working on a site using Classis ASP for a while (on my own personal server) however I've hit a stumbling block. I'm trying to get paging to work but for some reason nothing shows up on the pages, I cannot fathom it at all.
Basically the site is an advertisement board, on one page it shows the total of each item type, click on that and it shows those items but pages them.

```
<%
    If (Request.QueryString("type") <> "" ) Then
        Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rs.Open "select s.Unique_ID, s.Location,s.Extension,s.Item,s.Description,s.Price,s.Date_On_Sale,s.Type, s.Name, s.Date_Posted " & _
        " from tblSales s where Lower(s.Type) = Lower('" & Request.QueryString("type") &  "')" , objconn, 3, 3

        If (rs.BOF or rs.EOF) Then StrMsg = "<font color='red'> <b> System found no results for <u> " & Request.QueryString("type") & " </u>  </b></font>"
    End If
%>

<%response.Write(strQuery) %>  
<div id="midrow" style="clear:both;"> 
    <div class="center">     
         <p>To view the details of an item, simply click on desired item</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="board_bottomrow">
    <div class="center">



<% If StrMsg <> "" Then
Response.Write(StrMsg)
Else
      Dim bShowPages 
      rs.PageSize = 20
      nPageCount = rs.PageCount
      If nPageCount <2 Then 
      bShowPages = false 
      Else bShowPages = true 
      End If

      nPage = CLng(Request.QueryString("Page"))
      If (Request.QueryString("Page") = "") Then nPage = 1
      If nPage < 1 Or nPage > nPageCount Then
  nPage = 1
      End If

      item_type = Request.QueryString("type")

      rs.AbsolutePage = nPage

      %>

<div> <b>  <%= Request.QueryString("type") %> Items </b>  </div>
<br>

<table class="table_border" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="0" style="width:950px" id="items" >

<thead>
<th style="text-align:left"> <b> <font size="2"> Item  </font> </b> </th>
<th style="text-align:left"> <b> <font size="2">  Description </font> </b> </th>
<th style="text-align:left;"> <b> <font size="2"> Price </font> </b> </th>
<th style="text-align:left;"> <b> <font size="2"> Posted By  </font> </b> </th>
<th style="text-align:left;"> <b> <font size="2"> Extension </font> </b> </th>
<th style="text-align:left;"> <b> <font size="2"> Posted On  </font> </b> </th>
</thead>


<tbody>


<% 
  Response.Write(rs.AbsolutePage)
    While Not (rs.Eof Or rs.AbsolutePage <> nPage) %>
   <tr style="vertical-align:top">
<td> <a href='Board_Item.asp?link_id=<%=rs("Unique_ID")%>'> <%= rs("Item") %> </a> </td>
<td style="width:350px"> <%= rs("Description") %>  </td>
<td style="margin-left:10px"> £ <%= rs("Price") %> </td>
<td> <%= rs("Name") %> </td>
<td> <%= rs("Extension") %> </td>
<td> <%= rs("Date_Posted") %> </td>

  </tr>
 <%
rs.MoveNext()
  Wend  

 'Response.Write ("bShowPages " & bShowPages)
 %>


<!-- show pages only if pageCount > 1 -->
<%If bShowPages <> false Then%>
<tr style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
<td> Pages:  </td> <td colspan="5"> 
 <a href='Items.asp?type=<%=item_type%>&Page=1'> First </a>  
<a href='Items.asp?type=<%=item_type%>&Page=<%=nPage - 1%>'> Prev </a>  
<a href='Items.asp?type=<%=item_type%>&Page=<%=nPage + 1%>'> Next </a> 
 <a href='Items.asp?type=<%=item_type%>&Page=<%=nPageCount%>'> Last </a> 
 <td> </td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
 </table>
 <%End If%>

<% End If %>


</div>

<br>
```

Im pretty aware there is some bad coding in the sample, but it's a personal learning project for me at the moment, if anyone can see why this records wouldn't be displaying id be greatful. The pagenumbers all show up, just non of the records. Thanks.

Comment: Does it show if you change `While Not (rs.Eof Or rs.AbsolutePage <> nPage)` to just `While Not rs.Eof`

Comment: Ah yes it does display, although it displays all in one chunck i.e more than 20 records on the first page and then a few records on the second page are repeated...